# flutter defining a method named '<'

Tags: flutter

Estoy tratando de hacer una llamada a firebase para mostrar los datos dentro de la base de datos pero me sale este error:

```
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing method, or defining a method named '<'.

return StreamBuilder<Event>{
```

Este es mi codigo;

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:firebase_database/firebase_database.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(new MaterialApp(
   home: MyApp(),
  ));
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
 @override
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return new Scaffold(
    appBar: new AppBar(
      title: new Text("Firebase_Test"),
    ),
    body: new Container(
      child: new Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          new RaisedButton(
            child: new Text("Boton"),
            onPressed: (){
              new MyCard();
            },
          )
        ],
      ),
    ),
 );
 }
}

class MyCard extends StatelessWidget{

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context){
    return StreamBuilder<Event>{
      Stream:FirebaseDatabase.instance.reference().child("1").onValue,
      Builder:(context,snapshot){
        if (!snapshot.hasData){
          return Container(child: Center(child: new Text("No data")));
        }
        return ListView.builder(
          padding: EdgeInsets.all(8),
          reverse: true,
          itemBuilder: (_,int index){
            return ListTile(
              title: new Text(snapshot.data.snapshot.value.toString()),
            );
          },
        );
      }
    }
  }
```

}

**Nuevo codigo**

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:firebase_database/firebase_database.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(new MaterialApp(
   home: MyApp(),
  ));
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
 @override
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return new Scaffold(
    appBar: new AppBar(
      title: new Text("Firebase_Test"),
    ),
    body: new Container(
      child: new Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          new RaisedButton(
            child: new Text("Boton"),
            onPressed: (){
              new MyCard();
            },
          )
        ],
      ),
    ),
 );
 }
}

class MyCard extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return StreamBuilder(
      stream: FirebaseDatabase.instance.reference().child("this").onValue,
      builder: (context,snapshot) {
        if (!snapshot.hasData) {
          return new Container(child: new Center(child: new Text("Sin Archvivos")));
        }
        return new ListView.builder(
          padding: EdgeInsets.all(8),
          reverse: true,
          itemBuilder: (_, int index) {
            return new ListTile(
              title: new Text(snapshot.data.snapshot.value.toString()),
            );
          }
        );
      }
    );
  }
}
```

**Resultado de ejecutar flutter run**

```
C:\Users\Angel\Desktop\test1>flutter run
Using hardware rendering with device Android SDK built for x86. If you get graphics artifacts, consider enabling software rendering with
"--enable-software-rendering".
Launching lib/main.dart on Android SDK built for x86 in debug mode...
Initializing gradle...                                              1.6s
Resolving dependencies...                                          25.3s
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...
registerResGeneratingTask is deprecated, use registerGeneratedResFolders(FileCollection)

registerResGeneratingTask is deprecated, use registerGeneratedResFolders(FileCollection)

registerResGeneratingTask is deprecated, use registerGeneratedResFolders(FileCollection)

registerResGeneratingTask is deprecated, use registerGeneratedResFolders(FileCollection)

registerResGeneratingTask is deprecated, use registerGeneratedResFolders(FileCollection)
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...                              6.5s
Built build\app\outputs\apk\debug\app-debug.apk.
Syncing files to device Android SDK built for x86...
D/        (10013): HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0xe7e07bc0, tid 10037

D/EGL_emulation(10013): eglMakeCurrent: 0xe7d84080: ver 2 0 (tinfo 0xe7e7d1a0)
Syncing files to device Android SDK built for x86...             3,680ms (!)
```

**Firebase y emulador**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**Nueva captura**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tienes un error al momento de crear el `StreamBuilder`, cambia esto:

```
  return StreamBuilder<Event>{
```

Por esto:

```
  return StreamBuilder<Event>(
```

Veo más errores en tu código, ese widget `MyCard` no está haciendo nada.

Cambia esto:

```
    body: new Container(
          child: new Column(
            children: <Widget>[
              new RaisedButton(
                child: new Text("Boton"),
                onPressed: (){
                  new MyCard();
                },
              )
            ],
          ),
        ),
```

Por esto:

```
    body:  new MyCard()
```

Y revisa bien la referencia a esta colección:

```
 .child("this")
```

Según tu imagen de la bd de firebase podría ser así :

```
 .child("newfire-51c12")
```

Comment: ya hice el cambio pero no se muestra nada al oprimir el boton edite mi respuesta para que veas lo que he agregado

Comment: sale algún error en la consola? puedes mostrarnos la interfaz de la app ? también un pantallazo de la base de datos en firebase

Comment: listo añadi nueva información

Comment: revisa mi respuesta actualizada

Comment: gracias lo reviso... Me esta costando un poco esto de la programación móvil ya que vengo de Python

Comment: pero si lo cambio también se elimina el botón y mi intención es que al presionar el botón se muestren los datos

Comment: así es, pero para que necesitas el botón ?

Comment: es que es para una practica y me piden que conecte el botón a una función que devuelva los datos. De firebase. Por cierto con el código modificado me lanza una lista como de 12 elementos repeditos que dicen {descriotion:nueva, title:New}

Comment: Bueno, ya puedes ver el contenido, te recomiendo que leas un poco más de Flutter , https://flutter.dev/docs/development/ui/widgets-intro  ,  anda poco a poco, sino vas a terminar haciendo cosas sin entender.